# Codepen dashboard doesn't show content within iframe

Tags: html, iframe, codepen

I've created a pen like [this](https://codepen.io/mdbootstrap/pen/XzbNdx) which contains iframes. Inside a pen everything is correct but when I go to my codepen dashboard, it doesn't show content within an iframe - you can see this [here](https://codepen.io/mdbootstrap/pens/public/) - and I don't know why. Maybe you know what it depends on? Thanks.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mlOiXMvMaZo" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: I would guess that the preview image is taken before the remote content is loaded. This should probably be a question for the maintainers of Codepen rather then Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I know where to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already found your answer, but if I'm understanding the question correctly, it appears properly in Chrome, when I view your dashbaord:

[image]

Maybe you have to clear your browser cache?

I hope this helps.